# Free Commutative Monoid Quotient by Relations?

Tags: equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, monoid, toric-varieties

Say I have a commutative monoid $M$ that is generated by three elements $A,B,C$, where I have that $A+C=2B$. I want to write this a free (does that even mean anything?) monoid $\mathbb N^3$ with generators $X$, $Y$, $Z$ quotiented out by some equivalence relation $\sim$ that yields $[X]+[Z]=2[Y]$. Is there a way to do this?

If I was working with groups, I could just take the free abelian group generated by $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and then quotient out by the subgroup generated by $ X+Z-2Y$, but I don't have an inverse operation so I can't take that approach. Furthermore, I don't think there even exists a submonoid of $\mathbb N^3$ that when I quotient out $\mathbb N^3$ by I would get such a relation.

Indeed, suppose such a submonoid $P$ existed, then there is a projection map $\pi:\mathbb N^3\rightarrow \mathbb N^3/P$, and we would have that $\pi^{-1}(0)=P$. However, I think this map is somehow injective, because as far as I can see there is no linear combination of $[X]$, $[Y]$ and $[Z]$ over $\mathbb N$ that equals zero. If this is true, then no such such submonoid could exist as $P=\{0\}$, and clearly that quotient would just be $\mathbb N^3$.

I then suspect that there must be a way to write a congruence relation on $\mathbb N^3$ which yields this space, but I can't think of one that would work. So perhaps instead we take $\mathbb N^4$, with generators $X,Y,Z,Y^{-1}$, and then the submonoid $P$ generated by $\{X+Z+2Y^{-1}, Y+Y^{-1},Y^{-1}\}$. Then we would have that $X+Z\sim 2Y$, as:
\begin{align*}
(X+Z)+2Y^{-1}+2Y=2Y+(X+Z+2Y^{-1})
\end{align*}
but this then makes $Y\sim 0$, as $Y+(Y^{-1})=0+(Y+Y^{-1})$, so this doesn't work either.

Overall, I am just very confused. I know very little about monoids, and my motivation comes from trying to verify an isomorphism that my professor wrote down in our Toric Varieties course. Basically, we have the monoid $S\subset \mathbb Z^3$ generated by $e_1,e_2,-e_1+e_2$, where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the standard basis for the lattice, and she claimed that:
\begin{align}
\mathbb C[S]\cong \mathbb C[x,y,z]/\langle xz-y^2\rangle
\end{align}
I could get a well defined surjective map from the quotient polynomial to the $\mathbb C$-algebra induced by $S$, but showing that this map was either $a)$ injective, or $b)$ had a well defined inverse seems to hinge on saying something about $S$ as a quotient of a free monoid modulo some relations. Making this precise has been quite difficult.

Comment: You quotient by congruence, not by submonoid. For groups you do this too, its just not visible from the standard treatment of group theory.

Comment: @Jakobian What’s the equivalence relation?

Comment: As for the question I think you're totally confusing it, all you need to do is verify that the map $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]\to\mathbb{C}[S]$ has $\langle xz-y^2\rangle$ as kernel. Then use one of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: @Jakobian it’s difficult to to show that the kernel is contained in that ideal without being able to say anything about $S$ as a quotient

Comment: Note that $xz=y^2$ and $x+z=2y$ are the same relation written multiplicatively and additively. So the relation defining $S$ is exactly the same as the one defining $\langle xz-y^2\rangle$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I see that, which is why I want to know about how to quotient a free monoid to get this relation, because then this is clear. However, showing an arbitrary polynomial which map to zero under the obvious map lies in the desired deal is particularly difficult. Regardless, I’d still like to understand what equivalence relation on $\mathbb N^3$ yields this monoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your original question: We quotient by the equivalence relation defined in this way. Say an equivalence relation is "good" if $xRy$ implies $(x+z)R(y+z)$ and $(a + c)R(b+b)$. Consider all the good equivalence relations and take their intersection $\approx$. Since intersections of equivalence relations are still equivalence relations, we get to quotient by $\approx$. You can prove as an exercise that addition is well-defined on the quotient, and it gives you an equivalence relation.

Generally, given an algebraic structure $A$ (say monoid), you quotient not by some substructure, but a **congruence**, defined as a substructure of $A\times A$ satisfying reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. Note that this is more than an equivalence, because it is not just a subset but a substructure. So it also needs to be closed under algebraic operations.

In the case of groups, given a subgroup $R \subseteq G \times G$, $(x,y) \in R$ if and only if $(x y^{-1}, y y^{-1}) \in R$, since $(y,y)\in R$ by reflexivity, and $R$ is closed under multiplication and inverse. So we just need to know the subset $\{t \mid (t, 1) \in R\}$ to completely determine $R$. *Exercise*. Prove that $R$ is a congruence iff this subset is a normal subgroup od $G$. This justifies our quotienting by normal subgroups.

Comment: I guess your fix is to take all possible congruences in $\mathbb N^3\times \mathbb N^3$ that contain $(a+c,b+b)$, and take their intersection? I can see how this would give the relation I want, but how can I be sure it won't give other relations that I don't want? Specifically, how can I be sure that any map which satisfies $f:\mathbb N^3\rightarrow M$ satisfies $f(a+c)=f(2b)$, then I get a unique map $\tilde{f}:\mathbb N^3/\approx \rightarrow M$?

Comment: @Chris Consider the equivalence defined by $xRy \iff f(x) = f(y)$. This is a good relation, so the definition of $\approx$ already took the intersection over it. Since $f$ respects $R$ by definition, it respects $\approx$, so it gives a unique map $\tilde f$. This is a very general technique.

Comment: amazing thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but how exactly do we show that induced map $\mathbb N^3/\approx\rightarrow M$ where $M$ is the commuative monoid generated by $A, B$ and $C$ and $A+C=2B$ is injective?

Comment: @Chris How did you define $M$?

Comment: $M$ is the sub lattice of $\mathbb Z^3$ generated by $e_1, e_2, -e_1+e_2$

Comment: There's probably a typo.

Comment: You’re right it should be $e_1+e_2$, $e_2$, and $-e_1+e_2$, but I still can’t show injectivity

Comment: You just need to show that every good relation relates the desired elements, by using the condition $(a+c)R(b+b)$ and that $R$ is an equivalence relation.